# How to push items into an array where key is "specified key"?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array.

[image]

My code:

```
$colors = [];

foreach($bikegroup->bikes as $bike) {
    if(!in_array($bike->kleur, $colors)) {
        $colors[$bike->kleur]=[];
    }
}

dd($colors);
```

Each color has multiple sizes like:

```
"Satin black" => ['h43', 'h34', 'h76'];
```

How do i push an new array into the $colors array where $key = "Satin black"?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: please `dd` the `$bikegroup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use this:

```
$array['Satin black'][] = 'h99'; // where 'h99' is the new value
```

Or use `array.push()` like this:

```
array_push($array['Satin black'], 'h99');
```

**Update:** Check if the key/index exists:

```
if (array_key_exists('Satin black', $array)) {
    $array['Satin black'][] = 'h99'; // where 'h99' is the new value
}
```

Comment: Allright, this seems to get close. But how do i check if Satin black is a key in the array?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, do this:

```
$colors['Satin black'] = ['h43', 'h34', 'h76'];
```

Comment: This would change the value of Satin black, not adding it.